# RestSharp post image to WCF REST service

Tags: .net, rest, restsharp

I'm having some trouble uploading images to my server via RestSharp.

I have a Rest Wcf service that accepts a Stream. If I use the code below I always get this Exception:

> ProtocolViolationException Bytes to be written to the stream exceed
>   the Content-Length bytes size specified.

What settings to I need to configure... setting the content-length header seems to make no difference.

The server side doesn't receive an image, but some smaller stream of bytes.

Any help appreciated.

Client (test) Code:

```
byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes("small.jpg");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Length", int.MaxValue.ToString());//doesn't matter what length I put here
        request.AddFile("image/jpeg", (requestStream) =>
                                          {
                                              using (var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
                                              {
                                                  ms.CopyTo(requestStream, byteArray.Length);//doesn't matter whether I add second param or not
                                                  ms.Flush();
                                                  ms.Close();
                                              }
                                          },
                        "sample",
                        "image/jpeg");


        request.Method = Method.POST;
        client.ExecuteAsync(request, (response, a) =>
        {
            Assert.IsNotNull(response.Content);
            string content = response.Content;
            resetEvent.Set();
        });
```

Service Code (returns the Url of the stored image)

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "upload/{fileName}/{fileExtension}/{id}", Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Message UploadPhoto(string fileName, String fileExtension, string id, Stream fileContents);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Content-Length header is set automatically based on the content of the request body so you don't need to set it explicitly.

Comment: Hmm.. so perhaps the file is just too large?

Comment: you should just use the `AddFile()` overload that takes in a byte array.